# Get a JSON response to Android

Tags: android, json, web-services

I'm just trying to get a simple conversor from °C to °F in a Server (Django) The Django Backend is ok, but I only want a simple way to get that info and print that in an Android app:

> URL: 192.168.1.212:8000/c_f/4.0

And the response is:

```
{"far": 39.2}
```

I tryied, but I only find huge codes and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class sampleService extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet del = new HttpGet("192.168.1.212:8000/c_f/4.0");
        del.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        try {
            HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(del);
            String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
            JSONObject respJSON = new JSONObject(respStr);
            String far = respJSON.getString ("far"); //Check your type data to return in your web service.
            Log.d("Service", far);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Service","Error!", ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

}

Comment: Bur where do I get the JSONObject? And what does Boolean... params means?

Comment: JSONObject is a library incorpored in Android.
Boolean params is just beacause we need a value to execute an AsyncTask.
you need to do : new sampleService().execute(true);

Comment: And how can I call this class in my onClick Function in my view?

Comment: button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
new sampleService().execute(true);
                        }
                    });

Comment: Anyway, that stills not working, but at least this does not crash anymore. I dont know what happens, but it stops working in the try{} block.

Comment: What is the Exception?

Comment: Connection to http://192.168.1.212:8000 refued and Something in DefaultClientConnectionOperator.

Comment: That Error is because your server is not online in your network, check if you can access to webpage from the device web navigator or make ping to 192.168.1.212:8000 in your android device.

Comment: This is what i get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644026/fatal-exception-asynctask-3-in-json-response-for-android

Answer (score 0):

You can use the httppost and httpClient to enable to get the response from the web

example

```
String getURL = "192.168.1.212:8000/c_f/4.0";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(getURL);
HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(httppost);  
        HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity(); 
Lod.d("response", EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
```

Comment: I tried, but The app crashes! Do I need some permissions different that  android.permission.INTERNET?